# How to use React Bootstrap with Laravel

Tags: laravel, react-bootstrap

I'm currently using Laravel 5.6.  I have integrated bootstrap and would like to use the package [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).  For my component building.

Currently the components do not render properly.  I believe it's because it's conflicting with the Laravel bootstrap/

In app.js I've disabled:

```
// require('./bootstrap');
```

The component still does not appear correctly.

I also import this in my component:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

This causes my layout to change drastically.

Is there any specific way I can up my laravel project and be able to take advantage of the React Bootstrap components?

Comment: are you set the Laravel UI to react?

Answer (score -1):

you should run `npm install && npm run dev` commands and then it will work properly

this is the link from documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

Answer (score -1):

you can try adding bootstrap cdn on your blade file